# Local video (mp4) files stutter using Debian, but not when viewing youtube, flash etc

Tags: debian, video

My local video files (mp4) are stuttering (i.e. lagging, not playing smoothly) when I play them from the hard drive (SSD) or DVD. Online videos work fine. What could the problem be?

Specs:

```
1.86GHz × 2; 3 GB RAM
Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) 32-bit
```

lspci gives me:

```
VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV516/M64-S [Mobility Radeon X2300]
```

I am unable to elicit GPU information from my laptop using cpuid, hwinfo, hardinfo.

Comment: Which media player do  you use?

Comment: try `xv` output instead of `x11`